# vt-220 look-alike for linux?

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm going to give a presentation about using `vi`, and as a sort of fun nostalgia, I want to demonstrate some things like they used to be in the good ol' days, so I'd like to use a terminal program that looks like an old vt-220. I know that it is near-trivial to set up a desktop terminal emulator to have 80x25 characters in green or amber on a black background, but I just wondered if there is an emulator out there that looks like a proper glass-tty, just for the fun of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool-retro-term will probably fit your use case

https://github.com/Swordfish90/cool-retro-term